# Which of the following condition implies that the set $A$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Question :

Let $A$  be a subset of $\mathbb R$. Which of the following properties implies that $A$ is compact $?$

1. Every continous function $f :A  \rightarrow \mathbb R $ is bounded.
2. Every sequence $ \{ x_n \}$ in $A$ has a convergent subsequence  converging to a point in $A$.
3. There exist a continuous function from $A$ onto $[0,1]$.
4. There is no one-one and continuous function from $A$ onto $(0,1) $

In $(2)$ option we have result if $ (X , d)$, is a metric space, then $X$ is compact iff every sequence has a convergent subsequence. I have no idea in other option. Please give me hint how to verify other option. Thank you

Comment: Maybe it's wor dmentioning that topological spaces with property (1) are called [pseudocompact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocompact_space) ands pace with property (2) are called [sequentially compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequentially_compact_space). As you can read in the Wikipedia articles, for metric spaces these properties are equivalent to compactness.

Comment: Some related older posts on this site: 
[If every real-valued continuous function is bounded on X (metric space), then X is compact.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668905)
[$K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact space iff every continuous function in $K$ is bounded.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99637) Especially Mariano's answer to the latter question seems very concise and nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

2) is called sequential compactness (and there is a well-known theorem relating sequential compactness to compactness).

3) $\frac{1}{2}\sin(x)+\frac{1}{2}$ maps $\mathbb{R}$ to $[0, 1]$ and is continuous.

**Edit**

This is a hint assuming the question said: there is a continous 1-1 map from $A$ onto $(0,1)$...

4) $\arctan(x)$ is a continuous function that maps $\mathbb{R}$ to $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$.

**Better Hint**

This hint was provided by @Struggler (see comments).  If $A=\mathbb{N}$ then $A$ is certainly not compact and there is no continous 1-1 function from $A$ onto $(0, 1)$.  (Note: if we remove the onto condition then $f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$ is a 1-1 map from $\mathbb{N}$ into $(0, 1)$.)

Comment: @ Travis J : In 4), I am not understanding, what do you want to say

Comment: @Struggler, try shifting/stretching $\arctan(x)$ so that it maps $\mathbb{R}$ to $(0, 1)$.  This is sort of akin to what I said for (3) shifting and scaling $\sin(x)$ so that instead of mapping to $[-1, 1]$ it mapped to $[0, 1]$.

Comment: @ Travis : In 4), our aim to find a subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$ which is not compact in $\mathbb R$ and there is no continous one- one and onto mapping. I think set of natural number $\mathbb N$ which is not compact in $\mathbb R$ and there is no continous one -one and onto mapping from $\mathbb N$ to $(0,1)$. I think this is the counter example.

Comment: @Struggler, Ahh, I see that I did not read 4) properly.  I thought it said: there was a continuous one-to-one map from $A$ to $(0,1)$.  My suggestion for 4) is certainly not good then.  Your example certainly satisfies no continuous 1-1 map to $(0,1)$ and it is not compact.  So that seems good.

Comment: @TravisJ, why $\frac12\sin(x)+\frac12$? just $\sin(x)$ works, right?

Comment: @JessePFrancis, $\sin(x)$ maps the reals to $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score -1):

SIR MY DOUBT IN 1ST OPT HOW CAN IT BE CORRECT.
f(x)=x ; x€(0,1)
Then f(x)=(0,1) .Here f(x) is bounded in R and also continuous in (0,1)¢R.
But domain is not compact.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1791861)